# Eclipse: Failed to load the JNI shared library

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm

How do I resolve this error?

> Failed to load the JNI shared library "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\client\jvm.dll".

Comment: jdk is also for 32 or64 ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your Java and your eclipse are both the same bit (e.g. both 32-bit).

[Source](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/445913/)

Comment: Ok let I download it for 64 bit

Comment: Hi Thanks .. I do as you say and now It works.. :)